# How to convert day,month,year into date format?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to run a python script that converts day,month,year into date format.

I have attempted the following script;

```
# dateconvert2.py 
# Converts day month and year numbers into two date formats

def main():
    # get the day month and year
    day, month, year = eval(input("Please enter day, month, year numbers: "))

    date1 = str(month)+"/"+str(day)+"/"+str(year)

    months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "Novemeber", "December"]
    monthStr = months[month-1]
    date2 = monthStr+" " + str(day) + ", " + str(year)

    print("The date is", date1, "or", date2+ ".")
main()
```

The result should look like;

```
>>> Please enter day, month,  and year numbers: 24, 5, 2003
The date is 5/24/2003 or May 24, 2003.
```

As I ran the program, an error appeared saying that the line;

```
    monthStr = months[month-1]
```

had an index error.

What can I do to improve this? Please help

Comment: Take a look at [`strftime()` and `strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If

```
monthStr = months[month-1]
```

had an index error, it means `month` was either smaller than 1 or bigger than 12. You could check it's in the correct range before this line.

## A few notes

- `eval` is dangerous, and not needed in this case. You could use `split`, `map` and `int` to extract the integers.
- you could use `format` with `%02d` to show the dates, if you want to write it yourself
- [`strftime` and `strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) do exactly what you want. They parse a string to datetime and display a `datetime` in any given format.
- calendar already has [`month_name`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.month_name). The list has 13 elements though, and the first one is empty.

## Modified code :

```
def main():
    # get the day month and year
    day, month, year = map(int, input("Please enter day, month, year numbers: ").split(','))

    date1 = '%02d/%02d/%d' % (day, month, year)

    months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
    if month > 0 and month < 13:
        month_str = months[month-1]
        ## alternative :
        # import calendar
        # month_str = calendar.month_name[month]
        date2 = '%s %d, %d' % (month_str, day, year)
        print("The date is", date1, "or", date2+ ".")
    else:
        print("Invalid month")
main()
```

As an example :

```
Please enter day, month, year numbers: 24,12,2017
The date is 24/12/2017 or December 24, 2017.
```

but :

```
Please enter day, month, year numbers: 24,0,2017
Invalid month
```

Answer (score 0):

```
day, month, year = eval(input("Please enter day, month, year numbers: "))
```

eval() is unnecessary here, assuming your user knows to separate with commas you can just use:

```
day, month, year = input("Please enter comma seperated day, month, year numbers: ")
```

*may only work in 2.x see comments below, sorry for confusion*

then regarding inputs you should validate your data:

```
if 1 <= month <= 12:
    if (month in [1,3,5,7,8,10,12]) and (day != 31):
        print 'error'
    elif (month in [4,6,9,11]) and (day != 30):   
        print 'error'
    elif (month==2) and (day not in [28,29]):
        print 'error'
else:
    print 'error'
```

Comment: `eval(input("Please enter day, month, year numbers: "))` isn't valid Python2, so the OP must use Python3. `day, month, year = input("Please enter comma seperated day, month, year numbers: ")` isn't valid Python3.